# How to type into Ctrl + F text box using VBA and Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, ctrl

I know this question has been asked, but I can't find a clear answer to something I think should be pretty straight forward. I'm just trying to type the word "gainers" after running the code: `Application.SendKeys "^f", True` while using VBA within an Internet Explorer window.

Comment: Why? Do you need to establish that the text exists in the page content? If yes, read the text into variable and search. That's more robust.

Comment: I'm trying to select a link named "Gainers"

Comment: Can you post your code - it's possible, and more reliable to use the DOM object to fill in the text and click a button

Answer (score 0):

To search a string, for this instance "Gainers", in a search window in Internet explorer, you can separate out each letter of the string you're searching by placing each letter with a brace.

Code example:

```
application.SendKeys "{G}{a}{i}{n}{e}{r}{s}", true
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.